# Same question listed on three rows in the flag list

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, 10k-tools, flag-queue

[One identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713224/navigating-into-a-particular-view-controller-of-uitabbarcontroller) was listed three times on the flags page:

[image]

It probably should be on one line, not sure if it has 1 or 3 flags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One flag for one post. So you see the correct three since they have all been flagged.

- One is for the question.
- One is for a comment/edit as answer to their own question.
- One is for the other comment/edit as answer to, again, their own question.

Comment: Themself? I mean *themself*! **Themself**? Words cannot convey my despair that this has become acceptable. Can you at least avoid the construct by saying something like: *"Another for the first answer the OP posted for that question"*?

Comment: +1 @Sinan Because language need not be butchered by programmers.

Comment: Perhaps there should be something on each row that says what exactly is being flagged (the question, an answer, or a comment).

Comment: Clicking the link/title takes you directly to the flagged item.